# Some parent entity value cannot be saved to child entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When i save the job entity i was expecting that the child under job should also reflect in the db. The problem is that the ref_id and revision does not contain any value from the db.

here is the result from mysql db (removed confidential data)

[image]

This is my Job entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
public class Job implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2075866246194059832L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "ref_id")
private String refId;

@Column(name = "revision")
private int revision;

@Column(name = "appname")
private String appName;

@Column(name = "vendor")

private String vendor;

@Column(name = "version")
private String version;

@Column(name = "locale")
private String locale;

@Column(name = "platform")
private String platform;

@Column(name = "tier")
private String tier;

@Column(name = "category")
private String category;

@Column(name = "functional_tag")
private String functional;

@Column(name = "job_start_date")
private Date jobStartDate;

@Column(name = "author")
private String author;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

@Column(name = "release_version")
private String releaseVersion;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

And here is the child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7395753611385528546L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


@Column(name = "module_name")
private String moduleName;

@Column(name = "start_time")
private Date startTime;

@Column(name = "end_time")
private Date endTime;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

@Column(name = "machine_ip")
private String machineIp;

@Column(name = "data_center")
private String dataCenter;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "ref_id", referencedColumnName = "ref_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "revision", referencedColumnName = "revision")})
private Job job;

}
```

Here is the code that persist the entity

```
@Service
public class QReaderService {

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;
@Autowired
private TaskRepository taskRepository;


public boolean addJob(Job job) {

    Job previousJob = jobRepository.findByJobRefId(job.getRefId());
    if (previousJob == null) {
        **jobRepository.save(job);**
        return true;
    } else {
        switch (job.getStatus()) {
            case FAILED:
            case EXCEPTION:
                int revision = 0;
                revision += previousJob.getRevision();
                previousJob.setStatus(Status.FAILED);
                jobRepository.save(previousJob);
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

This is how i build the job entity

```
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setRefId("f78d9as7f98dsa7f97a97f98sda9f7");
    job.setAppName("appname");
    job.setLocale("locale");
    job.setPlatform("platform");
    job.setCategory("category");
    job.setReleaseVersion("1.1");
    job.setStatus(Status.PROCESSING);
    job.setAuthor("author");
    job.setFunctional("functional");
    job.setJobStartDate(new Date());
    job.setVersion("1.1");
    job.setTier("tier1");
    job.setVendor("vendor");

    Task task = new Task();
    task.setDescription("description");
    task.setDataCenter("dataCenter");
    task.setStartTime(new Date());
    task.setStatus(Status.PROCESSING);
    task.setMachineIp("ip");
    task.setModuleName("module");
    job.setTasks(new ArrayList<Task>(Arrays.asList(task)));

    jobRepository.save(job);
```

Comment: Post the code that persists these entities. Did you set both sides of the relationship?

Comment: Just updated the document

Answer (score 0):

To persist child entities when you call save on parent entity, both sides of the relations should be set.

```
job.setTasks(job.setTasks(new ArrayList<Task>(Arrays.asList(task)));

//Missing line //Important for persistence of child
task.setJob(job);
```

Hope this helps.